Where can I find CAD models of rockets with all the internals built also
When a company like SpaceX designs a rocket, they fully model the rocket in NX.
I'm just looking for an example of this as all I can find is surface level models of rockets. I want to be able to look inside and see the engine/other components.

Look for universities or other non-profits that are building rockets.  Don't expect that any commercial venture will share their tightly-held trade secrets, much less that any defense-related venture will share their even more tightly-held national secrets.
Example of a yet-to-be-launched liquid-fueled rocket effort, from a university near me: https://www.pdxaerospace.org/
